# Sencha touch 2 build production error

Tags: sencha-touch-2.1

[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Sencha\wamp\www\SLearn.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:256: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Sencha\wamp\www\SLearn.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:249: com.sencha.exceptions.ExScript: Wrapped com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException (x-app-build#291)
   runAppBuild (x-app-build:291)
   [anonymous] (x-app-build:571)
   x_app_build (x-app-build:569)
    (anonymous:1)

Comment: Whats that line !? Could you please post the code snippet at-least ?

Comment: that's the log from the command prompt. I used "sencha app build production". the debug version of the application had no errors and was working fine.

Comment: Have you updated recently to Sencha Touch 2.2.1?

Comment: yes I'm using the 2.2.1 version. I've tried building the production version on other systems as well, the same error is shown. I cant understand what the problem could be since the debug version wont show any error and the app works fine. anyways thanks for replying

Comment: I seem to have this same problem when I updated to ST 2.2.1.. I somehow managed to see that I need to update my Ruby as it has problem with SASS files. Couldn't get it work yet..

Comment: although i am using an older version of Ruby. let me try updating it.. thanks

Comment: I tried updating it doesn't work.. any other suggestion would be appreciated..

Comment: What version of Sencha CMD are you using?

Comment: I'm using the Sencha Cmd v3.1.2.342..

Comment: Solved!! initially I used Sencha Cmd v3.1.1.274 but I was building the app using Sencha Cmd v3.1.2.342.. hence the error

Answer (score 0):

Solved!! initially I used Sencha Cmd v3.1.1.274 but I was building the app using Sencha Cmd v3.1.2.342.. hence the error

thanks for help guys...

Comment: Can you post what steps did you take? I am unable to overcome this error?